# Недопонимание со статической функцией (с внутренним связыванием)

Tags: c, static

В файле `file.h` определена следующая функция:

```
static void fun(void)
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

Файл `file.c` содержит следующий код, который корректно выполняется:

```
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Собственно вопрос - почему функция `fun()` видна за пределами заголовочного файла, если она должна быть видна только внутри файла `file.h` ?

Comment: Вы путаете заголовочный файл - который не компилируется, а его текст просто вставляется в .c - и единицу трансляции - file.c...

Comment: @Harry действительно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экземпляры статических функций видны только в одной единице компиляции *(.h + .c => .o в Линукс)*.

Хедер файл - не компилируется а добавляется к тексту компиляции исходника `.c`.

А так как вы эту функцию записали в хедер файл, то будет реализовано то количество экземпляров функций, что и количество компиляций использующих включение данного хедера. И в каждой единице компиляции статическая функция не видит другого экземпляра.

```
.h + a.c = fun первый статический 
.h + b.c = fun второй статический 
     c.c = нет видимости ни к первому ни к второму
```

---

Ответ : функция `fun` статическая к единице компиляции, а не к хедер файлу.